# Connecting to backend server from app via HTTPS cause delays/timeouts

Tags: java, android, ssl, https

I'm developing an android app which connects to backend server via HTTPS. Everything is working properly when I use mobile data - no errors and other similar things. However, when I turn on WiFi and try to get some data from backend server I'm getting large delays (even 40 seconds) although I download just two lines of text, for example. I've also noticed that if I connect to backend server via HTTP, there is no problem using both mobile data and WiFi. I have tested many times if I set up SSL protocol properly and everything seems to be done properly.

I'm providing to you a piece of code, which is responsible for connecting with backend server from the app:

```
private boolean downloadData() {
        try {
            URI uri = new URI("https://www.example.com/resources/script/get_data.php");
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
            httpPost.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
            httpPost.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
            if(result.equals("error")) {
                return false;
            }
            result = result.replaceAll("\"", "\\\"");
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

            // code which receive and parse data from JSON

            return true;
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }
```

If you want to get some more information/pieces of code, write in comments.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is you server up to date, might be problems with the SSL / TLS version

Comment: I think, the server is up to date but you can tell me what I should check as I could miss something.

Comment: What version of the TLS protocol are you using ?

Comment: I cannot find the version but I'm using certificate provided by hosting on which I have my server and it's from Let's Encrypt

Comment: Can you do a curl -v https://...  ?

Comment: yes, I'm getting response immediately

Answer (score 0):

You need to trace you requests by some monitoring program. After that you can see what node creates a delay. And pls show this data.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's what you want, but I added trace logs in question below @EDIT

Comment: No @Replik surely means tracing your request on the client or server side using for instance wireshark.

Comment: @LaurentB, could you tell me in brief how to trace request with Wireshark. Is it possible to trace request when test the app via Android Studio or do I have to do it via phone?